# Stay logged in Android Studio- Kotlin with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I use SharedPreferences to stay logged in, and it works, but when I use it with Firebase the code doesn't work, I don't know if with firebase shared preferences doesn't work for staying logged in, or what I should do, I'm new with android studio and I search in youtube but I can't find how to stay logged in with firebase using Kotlin

Added code sample

For Firebase:

```
      logInButton.setOnClickListener {

        if(emailEditText.text.isNotEmpty() && passwordEditText.text.isNotEmpty()){

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditText.text.toString()
                ,passwordEditText.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    showHome(it.result?.user?.email?:"",ProviderType.BASIC)
                }else{
                    showAlert()
                }
            }
        }
    }


private fun showAlert(){
    val builder= AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Error")
    builder.setMessage("Error")
    builder.setPositiveButton("Accept",null)
    val dialog:AlertDialog=builder.create()
    dialog.show()


}

  private fun showHome(email:String,provider:ProviderType){
      val homeIntent= Intent(this,Menu::class.java).apply{
          putExtra("email",email)
          putExtra("provider",provider.name)
    }
    startActivity(homeIntent)
}
```

For shared preferences

```
  private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    var isRemember=false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    isRemember=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CHECKBOX",false )

    if (isRemember){
        val intent= Intent(this,Menu::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    fun checkUserValues(){

    }

    logInButton.setOnClickListener {

        val email: String =emailEditText.text.toString()
        val password: String = passwordEditText.text.toString()
        val checked:Boolean = check_remember.isChecked

        val editor : SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString("EMAIL",email)
        editor.putString("PASSWORD",password)
        editor.putBoolean("CHECKBOX",checked)
        editor.apply()

        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged in save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val intent=Intent(this,Menu::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> I use shared preferences to stay logged in,

Firebase already stores the user credentials and restores them when the user restarts the app. There is no code you need to write for this, as saving the data happens automatically when the user first signs in, and the information is then restored, when the user starts the app again.

I recommend removing the code where you persist the credentials to shared preferences, and leave that to Firebase.